# Where/what is the private variable in auto-implemented property?

Tags: c#

There is no (explicit)  reference to a firstName private variable which FirstName is supposed to be hiding. Could you explain how this works? 
I assume there is some private variable that is being getted and setted.
Thanks.

```
// auto-implemented property FirstName
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. See related links on the side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 3.0 :Automatic Properties - what would be the name of private variable created by compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277018/c-sharp-3-0-automatic-properties-what-would-be-the-name-of-private-variable-c)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically the compiler converts your code into something like this:

```
private string <__>firstName;

public string FirstName
{
    get { return <__>firstName; }
    set { <__>firstName = value; }
}
```

That's unlikely to be the exact name, but the use of angle brackets in the name is important - because it makes it an *unspeakable name*. (That's unofficial terminology, but widely used - I don't know whether Eric Lippert actually coined it, or whether he was just the first person to use it in something I read.) It's a name which isn't a valid C# identifier, but which the CLR is quite happy with. That has two benefits:

- The compiler doesn't need to worry about naming collisions with *your* identifiers
- The compiler doesn't need to worry about whether you're trying to refer to the field in your own code - you can't, because the name is unspeakable!

It uses the same technique for all kinds of other generated code - anonymous types, anonymous functions, iterator blocks etc.

Comment: I think I learned that argot from Anders; I don't know where he got it from.

Answer (score 8):

yes, 
`the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.` (c) [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

**EDIT:** 
When you define a property, compiler will emit 2 methods: `get_XXX` and `set_XXX`. When the C# compiler sees code that's trying to get or set a property, the compiler actually emits a call to one of these methods. (c) "CLR via C#"

Answer (score 4):

C# compiler creates the backing store field behind the scenes, you can try to decompile it. using Reflector. you will come to know, how it's created backing fields . 
[here's the same reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903235/auto-implemented-properties-c-sharp)

[MSDN Auto-Implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

[Auto implemented property](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson10.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The other guys have answered this, but a little further info ... you can find the backing field at run time using reflection. Look for fields with naming like << PropertyName>>k__BackingField.

Another post that may help:

- [Does an abstract property create a private backing field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877082/does-an-abstract-property-create-a-private-backing-field)