# Reliably detecting compiler generated classes in C# expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I'm building a C# expression-to-Javascript converter, along the lines of Linq-to-SQL, but I'm running into problems with compiler generated expression trees.

The particular problem I'm having is dealing with `MemberExpression` values which were compiler generated, but which DO NOT have the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` specified on their types.

Here's a cut-down version of what I've been trying:

```
void ProcessMemberExpression(MemberExpression memberX) {
    var expression = memberX.Expression;
    var expressionType = expression.Type;
    var customAttributes = expressionType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    var expressionTypeIsCompilerGenerated = customAttributes.Any(x => x is CompilerGeneratedAttribute);
    if (expressionTypeIsCompilerGenerated) {
        var memberExpressionValue = Expression.Lambda(memberX).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        ... do stuff ...
    }
    else {
        ... do other stuff ...
    }
}
```

Now, I have a Visual Studio debugging session open and I find this (running in the Immediate Window):

```
expressionType.Name
"<>c__DisplayClass64"
expressionType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
{object[0]}
expressionType.GetCustomAttributes(true).Length
0
```

So what I have here is an obviously compiler generated class with no custom attributes and hence no `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`!  Therefore, my code will `do other stuff`, when I intend it to just `do stuff`.

If anyone could help me out here, I'd be very grateful.  If at all possible, I'd really rather not do anything sordid like matching the `expressionType.Name` against something like `<>.*__DisplayClass`.

Comment: Anything that has a name that's invalid C# :)  The compiler intentionally uses names that aren't valid in C# but are valid in IL to ensure it won't conflict with anything in the actual source.

Comment: Thanks, James.  I'm hoping there's some less dreadful way of spotting these cases than asking "does the type name fail to match this particular regex"?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? What is the difference between the two branches in your code? Why is the difference there?

Comment: Note: If using Expressions with Reflection.Emit, there will be no classes generated.

Comment: @JamesManning didn't know that, but logical. nice, thanks! :)

Comment: @svick - The C# compiler is, in some cases (and for reasons that escape me, as an old compiler writer), wrapping primitive constants such as true and false in these compiler-generated classes which can only be accessed via private properties.  The only way to find out what is in such expressions, and thereby make a processing decision, is to evaluate them.

Comment: @Rafe But you didn't actually address my question: why do you have to do that for compiler-generated types, but not for normal types? What is the difference between the two for you?

Comment: @svick Sorry, perhaps I should have been more explicit.  I am writing a C# expression-tree-to-Javascript "compiler".  For example, I want the C# expression `() => x + 1 - y` to be converted to the Javascript expression `X + 1 - Y`, where X and Y are the Javascript-side names for the C# names x and y, resp.  Now, sometimes the C# compiler will hide that constant `1` (well, this actually happened to me with a bool, but that's minor detail) with a generated class which I *cannot* inspect.  Instead, I need to evaluate such terms and emit the JS for the resulting C# *value*, not the original expr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Jon Skeet's answer here, it sounds like checking for angle brackets will work.

[Where/what is the private variable in auto-implemented property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256594/where-what-is-the-private-variable-in-auto-implemented-property)

Comment: Gah, what a tragedy!  Is this really how third-party Linq-to-SQL converters handle the problem?  I find it amazing that they don't rigorously stick to the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` approach.  Oh, well - thanks for the link, Skeet is usually right on the money.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, although I haven't yet found the answer to my question in Matt's code.  What I meant to say earlier was that I can't believe *Microsoft* don't stick rigorously to using their `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`.  Most frustrating.