# What's meaning of `<>c.<>9`? I can't find any declaration of them, where are they from?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, decompiling

Here is an ASP.NET Core nuget package decompiled by JustDecompile, I can't understand the usage of `<>c.<>9`. I found that they have no declaration, it's very strange, the Nuget package name is `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical` and the class file name is `PhysicalFilesWatcher`.

[image: JustDecompile screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to be clearer about what you mean. You're seeing these declarations in source code? Or a decompiler like ILSpy?

Comment: it's decompiled by JustDecompile.

Comment: heres the real source: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/src/PhysicalFilesWatcher.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a part of some identifier in some compiler generated code (C# does not allow developer to use `<` and `>` in [identifier names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names#naming-rules), while the [IL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-code#intermediate-language--execution) does). There are multiple language features in C# which are expanded by compiler into code, for example [`await`'](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/)s, [auto-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256695/2501279), [`yield return`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273)'s, [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428624/2501279) and others.

**UPD**

In this case based on my decompilation it seems that it is compiler generated code for this `Action` lambda:

```
private static readonly Action<object> _cancelTokenSource = state => ((CancellationTokenSource)state).Cancel();
```

Which is initialized in generated static constructor via something like this:

```
PhysicalFilesWatcher._cancelTokenSource = new Action<object>((object) PhysicalFilesWatcher.'<>c.<>9, __methodptr(<. cctor>b__43_0));

[CompilerGenerated]
[Serializable]
private sealed class <>c
{
  public static readonly PhysicalFilesWatcher.<>c <>9;

  static <>c()
  {
    PhysicalFilesWatcher.<>c <>9 = new PhysicalFilesWatcher.<>c();
  }

  public <>c()
  {
    base..ctor();
  }

  internal void <. cctor>b__43_0(object state)
  {
    ((CancellationTokenSource) state).Cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what do they really delegate in this  situation?

Comment: @wulikunkun From just `'<>c.<>9'` - nope. What package? What class in that package?

Comment: it's 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical' package,and I found these code in PhysicalFilesWatcher class file.

Comment: Admire you so much!